# Word document is not created in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to take screenshot of the URLs using `puppeteer` and save screenshots in Word document, but it is not working giving me an error:

`Script encountered an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'creator')`

complete error:

`Script encountered an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'creator') at new ta (C:\Users\upadh\OneDrive\Desktop\dynamic-urls\node_modules\docx\build\index.js:2:310449) at runScript (C:\Users\upadh\OneDrive\Desktop\dynamic-urls\server.js:47:17)`

Using [docx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx).

Code -

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { Document, Packer, Media, Paragraph, TextRun } = require('docx');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

const urls = [
  'https://www.ptinews.com/press-release/pti/62401.html',
  'https://www.mysmartprice.com/gear/oneplus-nord-n30-5g-geekbench-listing-specifications-revealed/',
  'https://www.dnaindia.com/hindi/entertainment/bollywood/news-kailash-kher-blasts-organizers-khelo-india-university-games-2023-event-bbd-university-lucknow-4089120'
];

async function captureScreenshots() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    const url = urls[i];
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.screenshot({ path: `screenshot${i}.png` });
  }

  await browser.close();
}

async function createWordDocument() {
  const doc = new Document();
  const paragraph = new Paragraph();

  for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    const imagePath = `screenshot${i}.png`;
    const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(imagePath);
    const image = Media.addImage(doc, imageBuffer, 400, 300);
    paragraph.addRun(new TextRun().addImage(image));
  }

  doc.addParagraph(paragraph);

  const packer = new Packer();
  const buffer = await packer.toBuffer(doc);
  fs.writeFileSync('output.docx', buffer);

  console.log('Word document created successfully!');
}

async function runScript() {
  try {
    await captureScreenshots();
    const doc = new Document();  
    await createWordDocument();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Script encountered an error:', error);
  }
}

runScript();
```

for testing purpose as I have check, screenshot is captured and saved in the directory too, but word document is not creating and saving the screenshot in it.

Comment: if it is this [addImage](https://docx.js.org/api/classes/Media.html) then that method returns a void so `paragraph.addRun(new TextRun().addImage(image));` will just add a void to the paragraph. At a minimum do `var tr = new TextRun(); tr.addImage(image); paragraph.addRun(tr);` but maybe an even better option is to add an ImageRun: https://docx.js.org/#/usage/images to the paragraph.

Comment: I did try but still getting the same error.

Comment: On which line in the shown code does that exception occur? There is no `creator` variable or property in your code so it must be triggerred from a specific call.

Comment: getting error - `await createWordDocument();` in this function

Comment: Not working as I tried to use these methods - `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'documentCreator' before initialization`